# random samples and distributions in R

Tags: r, random, estimation

I'm trying to build an estimator to compare the asymptotics of the GLS and OLS estimators.
My idea is to try and see what happens at large samples, and with many of them.

Ideally, I would like to create a loop that would generate 6000 different random samples, of sizes 50 and 100 each, for different parameter values.

```
N=1000
n=c(50, 100)

#parameters
alpha0=1
beta0=1
gamma0=c(0, 0.1, 0.5)

alpha1=matrix(NA,N,6)
beta1=matrix(NA,N,6)
alpha2=matrix(NA,N,6)
beta2=matrix(NA,N,6)
alphaOLS=matrix(NA,N,6)
betaOLS=matrix(NA,N,6)
```

the different samples come from the combinations of gamma0 and n, which would equal 6 (times N) to get 6000.
My first idea was to build a loop for the generation of the random samples
the model I'm trying to work with is the following
y_i=alpha+beta*x_i+u_i

u_i=e_i*h(x_i)^(1/2)
and h(x)=exp(gamma0)

```
u <- list()


for (i in n) {
  for (k in gamma0) {
    x=rnorm(i,0,1)
    h=exp(gamma0[k]*x)
    e=rnorm(i,0,1)
    u[[i]] <- e*h^(1/2)
    
  }
  
}
```

The issue with this loop is that I'm only getting one random sample in x and e, and h is coming out as an empty matrix, and hence, u is also coming out empty.
h here should be a matrix where the columns correspond to x* the different values of gamma0.
e is supposed to be N(0,1) and u is meant to be the residual of the model

My ideal output should be get this loop to work, because from there on, I can sort my way around building an OLS and GLS estimator manually.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: As your sample size vary, would a list of residual values for each iteration be a solution for you?
If so, you can write before your loop `u <- list()` and inside your loop `u[[i]] <- e*h^(1/2)`. You would have to also name each list iteration so you can differentiate them.

Comment: thanks! this creates a u list, but the problem with x and e being just for one random sample size 100 persists.

Comment: I don't think it should persist, can you put your updated code please

Comment: I just updated the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, here we use directly `i` and `k` instead of `n` and `gamma0` in the loop.

```
### parameters
N <- 1000
n <- c(50, 100)

alpha0 <- 1
beta0 <- 1
gamma0 <- c(0, 0.1, 0.5)

### Initiating objects for the loop
u <- list()
num_iter <- 0

### Looping
for (i in n) {
  for (k in gamma0) {
    
    num_iter <- num_iter + 1
    
    x <- rnorm(i, 0, 1)
    h <- exp(k * x)
    
    e <- rnorm(i, 0, 1)
    u[[num_iter]] <- e * h^(1/2)
    names(u)[num_iter] <- paste("n:", i, ", gamma:", k, sep="", collapse=" ")
    
  }
}

### Display results
u
```

**Edit** (based on your latest request)

```
### Parameters for each scenario
N <- 1000
n <- c(50, 100)
gamma0 <- c(0, 0.1, 0.5)

### Initiating dataframes for each scenario
for (i in n) {
  for (k in gamma0) {
assign(paste("df_n", i, "gamma", k, sep=""), list())
  }
}

### Defining a dataframe with n rows (sample size) and N columns(simulation) for each of the 6 scenarios
df_n100gamma0 <- sapply(1:1000, function(x) rnorm(100, 0, 1) * exp(0 * rnorm(100, 0, 1))^(1/2))
df_n100gamma0.1 <- sapply(1:1000, function(x) rnorm(100, 0, 1) * exp(0.1 * rnorm(100, 0, 1))^(1/2))
df_n100gamma0.5 <- sapply(1:1000, function(x) rnorm(100, 0, 1) * exp(0.5 * rnorm(100, 0, 1))^(1/2))
df_n50gamma0 <- sapply(1:1000, function(x) rnorm(50, 0, 1) * exp(0 * rnorm(50, 0, 1))^(1/2))
df_n50gamma0.1 <- sapply(1:1000, function(x) rnorm(50, 0, 1) * exp(0.1 * rnorm(50, 0, 1))^(1/2))
df_n50gamma0.5 <- sapply(1:1000, function(x) rnorm(50, 0, 1) * exp(0.5 * rnorm(50, 0, 1))^(1/2))

### Dimension of 1 dataframe
dim(df_n100gamma0)

### Results
# First simulation
df_n100gamma0[, 1]

# 57th simulation
df_n100gamma0[, 57]
```

Comment: Sorry, actually I'm missing one more step. How do I loop this loop 1000 times?

Comment: Do you want to loop the same code 1000 times or add 1000 iterations on another parameter?

Comment: I want that loop you posted in your first answer to run 1000 times

Comment: So that would be 1000 times each combination of n and gamma right? I go in weekend and then I post an answer if nobody else has replied

Comment: @CF96 I updated the code to have 1000 columns, each corresponding to 1 simulation for 1 scenario (e.g. n=100 & gamma0=0). Do not hesitate to write `ls()` in the console to understand what the following part did: `### Initiating dataframes for each scenario`

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, avoid the loop altogether by using R's inherent vectorisation and the tidyverse's ability to process groups.  A good rule of thumb when using R is "if I'm thinking of using a `for` loop, there's probably a better way to do it"...

Here, I only do OLS for simplicity, but the extension to use both methods should be straightforward.  You can wrap the code in a function and provide parameters for, say, `N`, `n` and `gamma0` to provide even more generality.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)

# Create a tibble containing all combinations of the various design parameters
tibble() %>% 
       expand(
         # Sample=1:1000,
         # For speed
         Sample=1:10,
         Gamma0=c(0, 0.1, 0.5),
         n=c(50, 100),
         alpha0=1,
         beta0=1
       ) %>% 
       #  For each combination of design parameters...
       group_by(Gamma0, n, Sample, alpha0, beta0) %>% 
       group_map(
         function(.x, .y) {
           #  ... create some data.
           df <- .x %>% 
                    expand(
                      nesting(Gamma0, n, Sample, alpha0, beta0), 
                      ID=1:n
                    ) %>% 
                    mutate(
                      X=rnorm(n),
                      H=Gamma0 * X,
                      E=rnorm(n),
                      U=E*H^(1/2),
                      Y=alpha0 + beta0 * X + U
                    )
           # And analyse it. For example
           glm(Y ~ X, data=df) %>% 
             tidy() %>% 
             bind_cols(.y) %>% 
             add_column(model="OLS")
         },
         .keep=TRUE
       ) %>% 
       # Combine all analyses of each individual sample into a single tibble
       bind_rows()
# A tibble: 120 × 11
   term        estimate std.error statistic p.value Gamma0     n Sample alpha0 beta0 model
   <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>  <int>  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
 1 (Intercept)     1     7.39e-17   1.35e16       0      0    50      1      1     1 OLS  
 2 X               1     6.79e-17   1.47e16       0      0    50      1      1     1 OLS  
 3 (Intercept)     1     0        Inf             0      0    50      2      1     1 OLS  
 4 X               1     0        Inf             0      0    50      2      1     1 OLS  
 5 (Intercept)     1.00  8.55e-17   1.17e16       0      0    50      3      1     1 OLS  
 6 X               1     8.37e-17   1.19e16       0      0    50      3      1     1 OLS  
 7 (Intercept)     1     4.00e-17   2.50e16       0      0    50      4      1     1 OLS  
 8 X               1     3.56e-17   2.81e16       0      0    50      4      1     1 OLS  
 9 (Intercept)     1     4.22e-17   2.37e16       0      0    50      5      1     1 OLS  
10 X               1     4.40e-17   2.27e16       0      0    50      5      1     1 OLS  
# … with 110 more rows
```